# How to construct a parameterised UCCSD ansatz?

Tags: qiskit, chemistry

I want to try the UCC ansatz for problems other than quantum chemistry. For that I want to 'extract' the UCC ansatz (say from Qiskit) and supply it to my own VQE: I need a parameterised circuit where everything else is already set up.

How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the problem. Do you want to use the UCC ansatz from Qiskit (if yes, why not just import it) or create a new parameterized circuit (which you could also create with Qiskit)?

Answer (score 1):

`UCC` ansatz is already a parametrized circuit, since it extends [`EvolvedOperatorAnsatz`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/circuit/library/evolved_operator_ansatz.html#EvolvedOperatorAnsatz), which extends [`NLocal`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.NLocal.html). You can parametrize it manually using [`assign_parameters(parameters)`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.NLocal.assign_parameters.html?highlight=assign_parameters#qiskit.circuit.library.NLocal.assign_parameters) where `parameters` is a list of values. You can add the created circuit to your remaining circuit using standard `circuit.compose.`